# Does a thread synchronize with with the previous thread with same id?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

In C++11 there is `std::this_thread::get_id()` I can use to obtain an `std::thread::id` identifier of my thread. The standard says:

> 30.3.1.1
>
> 1. An object of type thread::id provides a unique identifier for each thread of execution and a single distinct value for all thread objects
>      that do not represent a thread of execution (30.3.1). Each thread of
>      execution has an associated thread::id object that is not equal to the
>      thread::id object of any other thread of execution and that is not
>      equal to the thread::id object of any std::thread object that does not
>      represent threads of execution.
> 2. thread::id shall be a trivially copyable class (Clause 9). The library may reuse the value of a thread::id of a terminated thread
>      that can no longer be joined.

My question is precisely about the case in which a new thread B, has the same `id` as an old thread A: will the thread B "see changes made by" thread A?

To be more specific consider this scenario:

Thread A does:

```
owner.store(std::this_thread::get_id()); //store A's 'id'
...some work...
owner.store(std::thread::id(),std::memory_order_relaxed); // clear
```

Thread B does:

```
assert(owner.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) != std::this_thread::get_id());
```

Will this assert hold?

The `owner.load` in Thread A and last `owner.store` in Thread B are intentionally "relaxed", as so there is no obvious "synchronize with" relation between the two, other than the one supposed in my question.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it would?

Comment: Considering what is written in the standard, and supposing the uniqueness is conceptualized considering physical time, that is at a given time no two threads id can  be identical, then to ensure the standard requirement the system must ensure that the end of A happens before the start of B.

Comment: @Oliv, yes my doubts about this whole topic really boil down to what is exactly the "relative times-space frame of reference" from which the standard defines the set of "threads of execution". English language (and probably most languages) are not very adequate to speak about things which might look different to different observers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[1] Considering what is written in the standard, and supposing the uniqueness is conceptualized considering physical time, that is at a given time no two threads id can be identical, then to ensure the standard requirement the system must ensure that the end of A happens before the start of B.

[2] The end of a stread happens after the execution of the function body that was launched at the start of this thread and the start of the thread happens before the execution of the body of this starting function. As specified in [basic.exec]/11:

> When calling a function (whether or not the function is inline), every value computation and side effect associated with any argument expression, or with the postfix expression designating the called function, is sequenced before execution of every expression or statement in the body of the called function. For each function invocation F, for every evaluation A that occurs within F and every evaluation B that does not occur within F but is evaluated on the same thread and as part of the same signal handler (if any), either A is sequenced before B or B is sequenced before A.

[1] and [2] implies that every computation in thread A happens before any computation in thread B.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is precisely about the case in which **a new thread B, has
>   the same id as an old thread A**: will the thread B "see changes made
>   by" thread A?

- So, your stipulation is exactly about the scenario when thread `A` is surely terminated (i.e. cannot be joined any more) and thread `B` has started, possibly reusing thread `A`'s ID.

in such case (threads `A` and `B` are subsequent and not concurrent) the assert will hold - even though its ID might be the same, by the time thread B has started, the owner's storage will be surely emptied (guaranteed by termination of the thread `A`)

**UPDATE: thanks to `@Yakk - Adam Nevraumont`'s comment - it was my overlook of write -> read operations under `relaxed order` - the above statement is false! i.e. the memory commit in the last operation of thread `A` will be asynchronous to the read of the thread `B` and hence the assert might not hold! (sorry for a confusion)**

otherwise (threads `A` and `B` are concurrent) they would never get the same ID and hence the assert would also hold.

Comment: Can you provide any citations from the C++ memory model for your claims?  Ie, that (2) means that everything the old thread formally happens-before everything in another thread eith a reused id?  I get why you might want this to be true, but I don't see evidence it is.

Comment: @Yakk - Adam Nevraumont, oh, you're right! somehow I assumed (don't ask me why) a consistency in modification order of atomic operations here (e.g. like in case of consecutive writes even under a `relaxed order`), which is of course not the case here - first was `write`, second is `read`, which provides then no guarantee on the order of outcome (memory commit indeed may happen *after* the read here). I'll update my post, thank you for keeping me honest!

Comment: I am not even sure if removig std::memory_order_relaxed changes my question much: AFAIU it would only mean that additionally things which happen in "..some work.." also become visible *IF* the thread B reads cleared value of `owner`. But AFAIU it does not change the fundamental issue of whether or not the read in B is *guaranteed* to happen after A's second write. After all there is a consistent order in which A writes `id`, B reads `id`, A clears it. Does the standard say anything about thread death also being part of the consistent ordering?

Comment: @qbolec: I believe it matters, look: with the `relaxed order` the last `store` operation in the thread `A` might not commit the actual changes (i.e. the owner's memory might not reflect clearing of the thread ID yet) but the thread `A` might be already terminated (hence its ID could potentially be reused). Once thread `B` starts, then it might already re-use the thread `A` ID  but in the `load` operation there's a chance of reading a stale information (i.e. the ID of the thread A - because memory commit has not been done yet). Thus, there's no guarantee that the assert would hold.

Comment: @Dmitry I agree with your description for `memory_order_relaxed`. I wonder what if there is no `memory_order_relaxed` in last store? Sure, on x86 on gcc this will lead to `mfence` and data has to be published. But perhaps on another platform, the only guarantee I have is that there is *some* total order between this second store of A, and load of B. Is there any guarantee as to what is the placement of "A terminates" in this ordering, or the relative ordering of "store" and "load"?

Comment: @qbolec: I think `mfence` is actually removed when `memory_order_relaxed` is in use. Contrary, using `mfence` will ensure global visibility for order of store/load and hence will provide the guarantee for the assert. For the other platforms, I want to believe that C++11 employs due required hw support when `memory_order_seq_cst` is used

Comment: @Dmitry I see I have trouble communicating my worry. Consider a case where instead of B, we have a totally unrelated thread C, which loads the value of `owner`. Would you agree, that there is nothing in the standard which says that C's load has to see the second write of A instead of the first one, or even the state before it? If so, then there must be some "additional" fact causing B's load to happen after A's writes. We feel that "A uses the same id as B" is such a fact, but does the standard actually say anything about impact of having same id on the total order of read/store?

Comment: @qbolec: there are couple things: `The library *may* reuse the value of a thread::id...` - there's no policy w.r.t. when/how the `id` value might get *reused*. another point, it would be logical to assume that the implementation of *reused* `id` internally guarantees the correct sequence within the thread library itself - it really then a matter of your code ensuring the read/write of the copy of thread `id` value has a guaranteed sequence within the concurrent threads

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194047/discussion-between-dmitry-and-qbolec).